# vectorize the following code in matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization

Suppose I have a vector, say S=1:10, and a fixed number K=5. Is there a way to vectorize the following code?

```
v=zeros(1:10);

for i=1:10
    if S(i)>K
        v(i)=S(i)-K;
    else 
        v(i)=0;
    end
end
```

Comment: I'm happy to see the answers helped you. Have you considered ["accepting"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) one of them by clicking the "v" sign beside the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for educational purposes:

```
v = S - K;
v(v<=0) = 0;
```

Note that this gives you some flexibility, you can easily replace the final `0` by `NaN` or even remove all these entries by replacing it with `[]`

Comment: I was blocked by the site for my several stupid questions. Finanlly I can upvote because my rep reached 200 in the other site. Thanks for all of your excellent answers.

Answer (score 4):

```
v = max(S-K, 0);
```

[space filler to make post long enough]

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
v = (S-K).*(S>K);
```